# Django channels, AttributeError

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I'm trying to learn how to send messages over a websocket using channels 2.

I'm trying just to send a simple message when a client connects but I keep getting Attribute Errors:

```py
class CameraOnlineConsumer(JsonWebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()
        return self.send({
            "type": "websocket.accept",
            "send": {'a': "Hi"}
        })
```

raises:

```
self.sendMessage(content.encode("utf8"), binary)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/camera_online/connect [127.0.0.1:36006]
```

changing to:

```py
 return self.send({
            "type": "websocket.accept",
            "send": "Hi"
        })
```

for example, returns the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try convert it to json like this ..


 import json    
    class CameraOnlineConsumer(JsonWebsocketConsumer):
            def connect(self):
                self.accept()
                return self.send(json.dumps({
                    "type": "websocket.accept",
                    "send": {'a': "Hi"}
                }))
```